# Exponential equation

Tags: functions, systems-of-equations, real-numbers

"Let $a, b\in(1, +\infty)$ fixed. Solve the equation:$a^{a^t}=b^{\frac{1}{t^2}\cdot b^\frac{1}{t}}$. "

This problem is from G.M. 3/2017. I can't solve it. For $t\geqslant0$ i showed that there is a unique solution by writing the equation $$t\cdot a^t \cdot \ln{a} = \frac{1}{t} \cdot b^\frac{1}{t} \cdot\ \ln{b}$$
in wich the left member is increasing and the right one is decreasing, but I couldn't find the solution, and for negative $t$ I don't know what to do.

Comment: Why only $t \geqslant 0$? It seems to me that this equation has a unique solution, which may or may not be non-negative.

Comment: @Ramil For 0⩾t we dont have those functions increasing and decreasing.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if we take $\log$ of both sides we get $$a^t=\frac{b^{1/t}}{t^2}\log_ab$$ We'll solve for $t\geq 0$. Putting $t=\log_ab$ we see that we are pretty close to equality. So why not take $t=\sqrt{\log_ab}$ to get rid of $t^2$? We will have $$a^\sqrt{log_ab}=b^\sqrt{log_ba}$$
which is obviously true. So for $t \geq 1$, the unique solution is $t=\sqrt{\log_ab}$